# minimumby function for Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a minimumby function for Julia (or some idiomatic substitute)? That is, I want something that works like:

```
julia> minimumby(length, ["Julion", "Julia", "Jule"])
"Jule"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not. This had been requested for years, but no-one got around to implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following, which seems to do what I want. Not sure how optimal it is.

```
function minimumby(keyf, a)
    keymap = item -> (keyf(item), item)
    keymin = (x, y) -> if y[1] < x[1] y else x end
    mapreduce(keymap, keymin, a)[2]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do is:

```
julia> reduce((a, b) -> length(a) < length(b) ? a : b, ["Julion", "Julia", "Jule"])

"Jule"
```